# Confusion taking a key( and value! ) from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, random, dictionary

So i have myself a bit of a problem. I have a dictionary, and i want to take a random choice  from that dictionary ***That does not return a list***.

random.choice() returns a list
random.sample() returns a list
random.keys() and random.values() both return lists.
I need a function that returns a key *and* its value.

Pseudo code follows:

```
import random
myDict = {"IronSword" : 15, "SteelSword" : 30, "Playing Cards" : 45, "Spider legs" : 60"}
d = random.functionNameHere(myDict, 1) # Same arguments as random.sample()
print d
```

Which should return something like {"SteelSword" : 30}, rather than ['SteelSword'].
Sorry if i'm a bit out of touch, and im skipping over something simple. I'm an intermediate python'er, and haven't gotten into string literals yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think `random.choice(myDict.items())` does what you want, but you should try some of those things again. I can't really see why `random.choice()` would be returning a list, what were you calling it with to get a list as the return value?

Comment: @mhlester That question is close, but OP says he doesn't want a list and the previous answer returns a list.

Comment: Where are you getting `random.keys()` and and `random.values()` from? Those aren't part of the python standard library! `random.choice` returns a single item from a list of items. If that that list happens to be comprised of other lists, or tuples, then `choice` may return a list or tuple.

Comment: @Joel That must be why the 1st line is `import random`

Comment: @user3508907 When you say you want the function to return both the key and value, and you don't want the function to return a list, what do you mean?  What type did you want back?  `tuple`, `dict`, or something else?

Comment: @Paul I wanted it to return a dict. Edit: "Which should return something like {"SteelSword" : 30}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a list is an intermediate step to making a random choice and then making an new dictionary:

```
 items = list(myDict.items())        # list of key/value pairs
 key, value = random.choice(items)   # pick a random pair
 print {key: value}                  # make a dictionary out of the result
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I understand most of this, but i dont get one thing; when you assign key, value = random.choice(items), what if two of them get assigned to a key? Or both to a value? Edit: Nevermind, i learned how to use items() ;D. I think this is my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you can just do this:

```
>>> dict(random.sample(myDict.items(), 1))
{'Playing Cards': 45}
```

`random.sample` returns a list of tuples, and you can feed that back into `dict` to make a dictionary with one entry.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` will take a random selection from an iterable.

```
from random import choice
d = dict([choice(myDict.items())])
print d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see what you want built in, write it:

```
def getOne():
    k = random.choice(myDict.keys())
    v = myDict[k]
    return (k,v)
```

Testing:

```
>>> getOne()
('SteelSword', 30)
>>> getOne()
('Spiderlegs', 60)
>>> getOne()
('Spiderlegs', 60)
>>> getOne()
('SteelSword', 30)
>>> getOne()
('Playing Cards', 45)
```

Comment: These still return lists, as it seems.

Comment: You can assign it to a left hand side as `(card, value) = getOne()`

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody made it to behave similar to `random.sample` yet :)

```
import random
myDict = {"IronSword" : 15, "SteelSword" : 30, "Playing Cards" : 45, "Spider legs" : 60}
random_keys = random.sample(myDict.keys(), 2)
d = {k: myDict[k] for k in random_keys}
return d
```